# Как встроить XAML в фрейм из другого проекта?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Так не видит UserControl1.xaml (он в другом проекте Apps_2)

```
 var fra = new Frame();

 fra.Source = new Uri("Apps_2.UserControl1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: Прикрепите структуру проектов чтоли

Comment: Не, не думаю, что на другой проект можно вот так просто сослаться через точку. Почему не pack URI?